# Running Couchbase under GCE Docker and getting error about max number of files

Tags: couchbase, docker, google-compute-engine

When I run Couchbase server in a Docker container on GCE, using the [ncolomer/couchbase](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ncolomer/couchbase/) image, I'm getting this error:

```
The maximum number of open files for the couchbase user is set too low.
It must be at least 10240. Normally this can be increased by adding
the following lines to /etc/security/limits.conf:

couchbase              soft    nofile                  <value>
couchbase              hard    nofile                  <value>

Where <value> is greater than 10240.
```

The docs in [ncolomer/couchbase](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ncolomer/couchbase/) are recommending to update `/etc/init/docker.conf` and add `limit nofile 262144`, but I'm not sure that's even available when using Docker under GCE.

I see a few options:

- In the Dockerfile, run a script to modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` as suggested by the couchbase error.
- Call `ulimit -n 64000` in the Dockerfile

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with ulimit is that the limits are bounded by the limits of the docker host process.
This is related to the known [#4717](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4717) (and to a lesser extent [#1916](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1916)) Docker issue.

As I understand, the two options you mentioned should not work since it will only set ulimit on the child process (i.e. the container). From there, I see no choice but set the correct ulimit on the host before trying to increase it on your container.

The documented procedure should work fine, until you have the possibility to apply it.
I don't know the GCE platform very well, but if you have a root access to your instance, you should just apply the changes to the `/etc/init/docker.conf` file, restart the Docker service and fire up the Couchbase container.

Comment: I managed to get this to work on GCE by doing:

1) Edit /etc/default/docker
2) Add a new line in the file with: ulimit -n 262144
3) Restart the GCE instance in the GCE web admin 

Note: I initially tried restarting just the docker service rather than the whole instance, but got an error and couldn't figure out why